# Looking for a word for an annoying person

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for an annoying person? I'm not just looking for synonyms of annoying.

Comment: What did a thesaurus suggest?

Comment: If you're not looking for synonyms, what are you looking for? You need to describe what you're trying to express, and hopefully also provide an example sentence for the type of word you're looking for. (What's wrong with *annoying* in the first place?)

Answer (score 1):

It would depend on how they're annoying.

If they are annoying in a little sister or little brother sort of way, try "pest".

If they are annoying in an unwanted suitor way, especially if 'suitor' is very much a euphemism, try "creep".

If they are annoying in a general way, they may be a "loudmouth" (self-evident), a "nerd" (annoying in that slow-to-develop socially way), or even a "busybody" (in this case, more in the personally nosy way than in the gossipy way).

In general, all of these people are "nuisances".

(But these are also given as nouns, and most won't work as direct substitutes for the adjective annoying.)

Comment: Exactly right. There are thousands of terms for annoying persons. They're one of our favorite conversational topics, and new ones are made up daily. They all depend on the context they occur in, and the presuppositions and entailments it provides for interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

**irksome**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/irksome)
adj.

> Causing annoyance, weariness, or vexation: irksome duties; irksome
>   restrictions;

As in:

an **irksome** person

Answer (score 0):

This might depend on the context of your need for the word, but maybe **pest** or **nuisance**?